# Cannot run this program neither with nor without sudo

Tags: sudo, texlive

I tried to run this program (texlive package manager):

```
tlmgr install
```

and got this error:

```
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2012/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
```

So I tried:

```
sudo tlmgr install
```

and got:

```
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

Why doesn't sudo find the program? And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sudo seems to change your environment. You can try to run the command with full path:

```
sudo /usr/bin/tlmgr install
```

Also worth a try is to run sudo with `-E`:

```
sudo -E tlmgr install
```

Comment: Based on your first answer, what worked for me is: "sudo \`which tlmgr\` install"

Answer (score 1):

Try `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` and then `tlmgr install`.

Alternatively, try `sudo sh -l -c tlmgr install`